# Which option is better ? use the old version of ruby from centos packages or use a the newest installed manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos

Now i'm starting a new project on rails, but the packages for ruby from CentOs corresponds to an older version, so i decided to install the latest version manually.  is this a good idea for a production enviroment?, considering the maintanability problems that comes without using the version from CentOs.
I have searched and i've found some discussions about this issue  http://lwn.net/Articles/423732/ .
But i haven't found yet a good answer to this problem.

Any help? Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

You should develop with the same version of Ruby that is used in your Production environment, and you should manage that version of Ruby on your dev machine using RVM.